# Getting recycle view childview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using recycle view ,which has multiple input types. I would like to get the input types values been provided by the user on click of a button which I have out of Recycle view list.

Assume checklist adapter has 10 items and after 4th(i.e.,0,1,2,3) items I am finding no value so child view becomes null

```
 View childView;
    for (int i = 0; i < checklistsAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
     RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder =
                        recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);

                childView = (View) recyclerView.getChildAt(holder.getLayoutPosition());
    }
```

I have also tried with adapter position.

How can I Solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view Reuses child views so you should create view every time new.

```
@Override
public void onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) 
{
    ChildViewHolder holder = null;
    if (holder == null) 
    {
        ConvertView =recyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
        holder = new ChildViewHolder(convertView);
    } else {
        holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return holder;
}

static final class ChildViewHolder extends ViewHolder 
{
    private TextView Photo;
    public ChildViewHolder(View convertView)         
    { 
        super(convertView);mPhoto = (TextView)        
        mSubUnitProperty.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        convertView.setTag(this);}
    }
}
```